# Get rows only missing a certain type of row

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I trying to find customers without a specific address type, starting from this :

```
SELECT C.NAME, CA.ADDRESSTYPE, CA.ADDRESS
FROM CUSTOMER C
INNER JOIN CUSTOMERADDRESS CA
ON CA.CUSTOMERUUID = C.UUID
```

| NAME | ADDRESSTYPE | ADDRESS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Paul | Invoice | ... |
| Paul | Shipping | ... |
| Paul | Shipping | ... |
| Bill | Shipping | ... |

How can I get only values form customers without invoice OR shipping address, in that case Bill (missing invoice)

| NAME | ADDRESSTYPE | ADDRESS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Bill | Shipping | ... |

The only idea (bad ?), I'm having is to GROUP BY, LISTAGG addresstype and then SELECT rows having the LISTAGG(...) LIKE '%Invoice%' AND LIKE '%Shipping'%, but I think for a huge amount of adresses to parse string like that.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . Generate a list of all customers and address types and then filter out the ones that exist:

```
select ca.name, adt.addresstype
from customer c cross join
     (select 'Invoice' as addresstype from dual union all
      select 'Shipping' as addresstype from dual
     ) adt left join
     customeraddress ca
     on ca.name = c.name and ca.addresstype = adt.addresstype
where ca.name is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be a way, by counting the occurrences of addresses of given types for each customer (the inner query) and then using this counts as a filter to only get customers with a missing address:

```
select NAME, ADDRESSTYPE, ADDRESS
from
(
    select c.name, ca.ADDRESSTYPE, ca.ADDRESS,
           count(case when ADDRESSTYPE ='Invoice'  then 1 end) over (partition by c.name) as n_invoice,
           count(case when ADDRESSTYPE ='Shipping' then 1 end) over (partition by c.name) as n_shipping 
    from customer C
        inner join CUSTOMERADDRESS ca
          on CA.CUSTOMERUUID = C.UUID
)
where n_invoice = 0 OR n_shipping = 0
```

With data like yours, this would give:

```
NAME ADDRESSTYPE ADDRESS
---- ----------- -------
Bill Shipping    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use an inner select to make a list the user ids that mach the criteria and then join this list just to remove what is not relevant:

```
select c.name, ca.addresstype, ca.address
from customer c 
join customeraddress ca on ca.customeruuid = c.uuid
join (
    select customeruuid 
    from customeraddress 
    where addresstype in ('Invoice', 'Shipping')
    group by customeruuid
    having count(*) < 2
) t on t.customeruuid = c.uuid
```

Answer (score 0):

I used a COUNT() OVER() to count the 'Shipping' addresses and the others (I can have more than 'Invoice') and get only with >= 1 (minimum 1 'Shipping' address) and then JOIN to remove the good ones.

Thanks all for your help/time.

Regards.